# Wix installer adding separate version for upgrade of application instead of removing and adding new entry in add remove programs

Tags: wix

My question is that when i run an upgrade installer over existing major installation of the product, i get two separate entries in ARP both for initial and upgraded versions.
For example:- Initial version is 4.1.0.0 and update is 4.1.0.1, the i get both these entries in ARP.
I tried making the product code same for both as its a minor upgrade, but at that time i get an error that the product is already installed.
Also i came across a point that an .msi package ignores the forth position in version?
Please confirm.
Thanks

Comment: I cannot understand anything from this. Could you please structure your post such that a concise question stands out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that Windows Installer uses only the first three fields of the product version. If you include a fourth field in your product version, the installer ignores the fourth field.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some of your WiX code that'd be great, but until then please try the following:

1. Make sure the Upgrade code **the same** for both versions
2. Make sure the Product code **is different**
3. Make sure the version number is incremented
4. Check if a previous version of the product exists and if so remove it before installing the new version

Check the answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341845/getting-an-install-to-upgrade-using-wix-old-installer-created-not-using-wix/3352299#3352299), and DAVID GARDINER's [blog](http://david.gardiner.net.au/2008/10/major-upgrades-with-wix.html) that I used in solving it.